# Django/Wagtail some images upload error 500

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, wagtail

Am using [Wagtail](http://wagtail.io) (Django variant CMS) in virtualenv, on FastCGI + Apache + shared hosting.

When uploading images via the built-in Wagtail Image Uploader, certain images work and compile correctly whilst certain uploads cause a 500 Internal Server Error.

Have tried looking for a pattern in types of images that cause the Error but can't spot any similarities.

I am able to upload various JPGs, GIFs, PNGs, 
sizes varied from 88KB to 236KB, 
largest dimensions are 1000px x 950px

[image: images uploaded]

The files causing errors are also variety of JPGs, GIFs, PNGs. I cannot upload anything bigger than 300KB, although some files that are only 100KB or less also cause 500 error.
Uploading via django-admin causes the same issues.

The images work when I upload through sftp and cpanel so there's no problem there.

Wagtail uses `Pillow` for image handling.

I'm not sure where to begin looking for this. Is it a Pillow or Django error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suspect your web server is setting a limit on request sizes - we've encountered similar things when deploying on nginx, which imposes a 1 Mb limit on requests out-of-the-box. (For nginx, the relevant setting is `client_max_body_size`.) If you're seeing a plain 500 Internal Server Error page rather than a Django error, that does suggest that the error is happening at the web server level rather than within Django... you'll hopefully get a more informative error message if you check the web server's error log.

One easy check you can try is to upload the same files in Wagtail's 'Documents' area - this doesn't do any kind of processing on the files (it only stores them), so if the uploads are still failing there, that eliminates Pillow from the possibilities.

Comment: Tried that, I think you're right again. Wasn't sure because my server error log was blank as well. But then again, I don't get to view the full error log. Will get my hosting to adjust `FcgidMaxRequestLen` value. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Same Error occurred to me but in my case, I was using apache2 web server in Ubuntu VPS.

but doing

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data mysite/
```

and

```
sudo chmod 755 mysite/media
```

fixes the problem.